# Express - How to serve a CSV from a remote server?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have a simple node/express API with one route. In this route, I want to make an API request to a 3rd party service that sends back a CSV. In turn, I want to send that CSV as a response.

I have this but feel like there might be something fundamental that I am missing:

```
//get csv from remote server
let csv = await axios.get('https://api.com/csv', {
    responseType: 'blob'
})
//serve that csv as a response
res.send(csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use axios like this.

```
    axios.get('https://api.com/csv', {
      responseType: 'blob'
     })
      .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        res.send(response);
      })
```

for more info refer this https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: my bad I forgot to add the await. the problem is that both with async-await and promises I get "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: According to your error you can not directly send API response, because response have some prototype function and while use res.send it try to convert data in json.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pipe for httpStream. If file size is huge this way it will be very fast. This is using nodejs inbuilt http module. Hope this will help you.

```
app.get('/path',(req,res)=>{
var options = {
    hostname: 'hostname',
    port: 80,
    path: '/path',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {

    }
  };

  var req = http.request(options, (response) => {

    response.pipe(res).on('error',(error)=>{
        console.log('Error');
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
  });
  req.end();
});
```